# Select a document from Mongodb by providing param in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to request a certain userId via NodeJs but I always receive all documents from MongoDb, independent of the userId I provide.

This is my route:

```
router.get('/wallet/showWallet/', walletController.showWallet)
```

Controller:

```
const showWallet = async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        let user = req.query.userId;
        const wallet = await walletService.getWalletById(user);
        res.json(wallet);
     } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: error})
     }
}
```

Service:

```
function walletService() {
    function getWalletById(user) {
        try {
            const walletResponse =  walletModel.find({userId: new ObjectId(user)}, {amount: 1, _id: 0});1, _id: 0});
            return walletResponse;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Wallet not found. ${error}`)
        }       
    }
    return {
        getWalletById: getWalletById,
    }
}
```

Model:

```
const mongoose  = require("mongoose")

const walletModel = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref : 'User'
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number
    },
    last_recharge_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    expiry_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    isDeleted: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    isActive: {
        isActive: Boolean
    },
})

const wallet = mongoose.model("wallets", walletModel)
module.exports = wallet;
```

Postman:

https://someUrl/api/wallet/showWallet?userId=626b9f5908b0fef1b09a55e4

MongoDb:

[image]

Result from Postman:

[image]

I really cannot find a way to solve this problem!

Maybe somebody can help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question?

Comment: only one user id in your collection for all the docs

Comment: @Gibbs: Okay, I think I understood it partly. Still, when I do a request with an incorrect userId then I always receive all documents and all fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused by the projection syntax you are using.
try this one

```
walletModel.find(
  { userId: new ObjectId(user) },
  { projection: { amount: 1, _id: 0 } }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one :

```js
function walletService() {
    function getWalletById(user) {
        try {
            const walletResponse =  walletModel.findOne({userId: user}, {amount: 1, _id: 0});1, _id: 0});
            return walletResponse;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Wallet not found. ${error}`)
        }       
    }
    return {
        getWalletById: getWalletById,
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to change it to: const walletResponse =  walletModel.findOne({id: userId}, {amount: 1, _id: 0});

Maybe it was a copy&paste error?

However, it still returns both entries in Postman and it shows all fields.
It does not matter whether the userId is available or not.

Comment: please explain more...

Comment: I added two pictures to my original request.
Although I have two entries in MongoDb, Postman returns something completely different, but maybe I understand MongoDb not good enough...